# Prop: $T$ is a topology on $X$

Tags: general-topology

Suppose that $S$ is the collections of subsets of $X$. Further suppose that $\emptyset$ and $X$ are in $S$ and that finite unions and arbitary intersections of elements of $S$ are in $S$.

**Prop:** $T = \{X-A:A\in S\}$ is a topology on $X$.

**Pf:** We first check that $X-\emptyset = X$ and $X-X = \emptyset$. Assume that $\{A_n\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}\in S$ is a collection of subsets of $X$. Then, $X-(\bigcup_{n}A_n) = \bigcap_{n} (X-A_n) \in T$ and $X-(\bigcap_{n} A_n) = \bigcup_{n}(X-A_n) \in T$. Thus, $T$ is a topology on $X$.

Answer (score 2):

The proof is essentially correct, but if I were you I would elaborate on the fact that an arbitrary union in $T$ corresponds to the complement of a finite intersection in $S$, and similarly a finite intersection $T$ can be written as the complement of an arbitrary union in $S$.

Comment: I feel like its completely fine :)

Comment: The $\bigcup_n$ is a bit worrying though!

Answer (score 1):

You checked that $\emptyset,X\in T$; that's fine.

Then you wrote “Assume that $\{A_n\}_{n\in\mathbb N}\in S$ is a collection of subsets of $X$.” That makes no sense:

- the notation $\{A_n\}_{n\in\mathbb N}$ implies that the $A_n$'s form a *sequence* of elements of $S$; you should be dealing with *arbitrary* collections of elements $S$;
- it makes no sense to say that $\{A_n\}_{n\in\mathbb N}\in S$; *each* $A_n$ is an element of $S$.

Finally, all that you are assuming about unions is that *finite* unions of elements of $S$ are in $S$. Therefore, you have no reason to assert that $X-\left(\bigcup_{n}A_n\right)\in S$.

Answer (score 1):

Be more precise:

$\emptyset,X$ are OK.

If $O_i, i \in F$ is a *finite* family from $\mathcal{T}$, we know that $O_i = X - S_i$ for $S_i \in \mathcal{S}$, $i \in F$. As $\mathcal{S}$ is closed under finite unions, $\bigcup_{i \in F} S_i \in \mathcal{S}$ and so $$X-\bigcup_{i \in F} S_i = \bigcap_{i \in F} (X - S_i) = \bigcap_{i \in F} O_i \in \mathcal{T}$$

which takes care of finite intersections.

If $O_i, i \in I$ is an *arbitrary* family from $\mathcal{T}$, again for all $i$, $O_i = X-S_i$ for some $S_i \in \mathcal{S}$ and so $\bigcap_{i \in I} S_i \in \mathcal{S}$ by the assumptions on $\mathcal{S}$ and so

$$X-\bigcap_{i \in F} S_i = \bigcup_{i \in F} (X - S_i) = \bigcup_{i \in F} O_i \in \mathcal{T}$$

which does for all unions.